# How to exclude fields of has_many associations when rendering xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, has-many

Part 1.

I have a `Series` which `has_many :articles`. In my `show` action, if `xml` is requested, I'd like to include all the associated `:articles`, but I really only want three of the fields: `:title`, `:date`, and `:id`

How can I do this?

Part 2.

Instead of doing this from the controller, I wonder if it would be better just to override `to_xml` in my model. Is this good practice? How would I do this?

Thanks so much!

**Edit**

Sector was almost right, but it needs to be a hash:

```
render :xml => @series.to_xml(:include => { :articles => { :only => [:title, :date, :id] } })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 1

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.xml {
    render :xml => @series.to_xml(:include => { :articles => { :only => [:title, :date, :id] } })
  }
end
```

Part 2

Controller is good place for this

Comment: This gives me the error `undefined method `macro' for nil:NilClass`